# How to send signature in http request headers

Tags: java, arrays, httprequest, signature

I want send signature in http headers. So I have test app that generate signature as byte array and I want print it and insert in request header, but dont know the best way to cast byte array to string and then parse this input string in my filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert `byte[]` to `String` when you send Signature in `http` header

```
byte[] signatures = ...
String signatureAsString = BaseEncoding.base64().encode ( signatures );
// Add signatureAsString as a HTTP header X-SIGN
```

To get signature in Http Header in `Servlet` Filter

```
// ServletRequest request
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)request;   
String signature = req.getHeader("X-SIGN");
byte[] bytes = BaseEncoding.base64().decode ( signature  );
```

I used `Google Guava BaseEncoding` for encoding/decoding. You can use any `Base64`, `Base16` encoding API.